# Can I Mutate a List Conditionally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This has probably already been answered but I couldn't find it in my search.

In Python 3, I find myself writing code that looks like this a lot:

```
def func():
    for item in list_A:
        if item == 'duck': list_B.append(0)
        elif item == 'goose': list_B.append(1)
        else: list_B.append(item)
    list_A = list_B
```

My intent is to change the values in list_A conditionally. For example:

```
list_A = ['duck', 'duck', 'goose', 'duck', 'chicken']
func(list_A) -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 'chicken']
```

Ideally though, I would like to do this without creating a second list. I'd like to find something like the following psuedo-code:

```
list_A = [(if item == 'duck': 0, elif item == 'goose': 1, else: item) for item in list_A]
```

My hunch is that the above would not work because you cannot mutate a list while iterating through it (?) but if anybody has something better than my original method I would be really interested to know about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fine to replace elements in a list while iterating. The problem is *structural* modification - operations that add elements, remove them, or otherwise cause elements to be shifted around.

That said, creating a second list is usually easier to get right, and often faster.

If you want to go with the mutation approach anyway, here's one way you could do it:

```
for i, item in enumerate(l):
     if item == 'duck':
         l[i] = 0
     elif item == 'goose':
         l[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(list_a):
  dict_a = {"duck":0,"goose":1}
  return [dict_a.get(item,item) for item in list_a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict and then use that for your mapping. In this case it's fine to mutate the list while iterating over it because you're a) not changing an item you haven't read yet and b) not changing the length of the list. To keep the code more compact you can use `dict.get()` to cover the else case:

```
mapping = {'duck': 0, 'goose': 1}
for i, val in enumerate(list_A):
    list_A[i] = mapping.get(val, val)
```

or a bit faster but a bit more code:

```
mapping = {'duck': 0, 'goose': 1}
for i, val in enumerate(list_A):
    if val in mapping:
        list_A[i] = mapping[val]
```

If you're ok with creating a new list, you can for example do

```
mapping = {'duck': 0, 'goose': 1}
list_B = [mapping.get(val, val) for val in list_A]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func():
    list_A=['duck','dd']
    list_B=[]   
    dic = {'duck':0,'goose':1}
    for item in list_A:
        list_B.append(dic[item]) if item in dic  else list_B.append(item)

    print(list_B)

print(func())
```

output

```
[0, 'dd']
```